# Using the conv command to calculate unit impulse function convolution

Tags: matlab, convolution

I was going to calculate the convolution of two unit impulse functions, but I realized that I wasn't sure about how to represent them in Matlab.  Can the convolution between unit impulse functions such as δ[n]*δ[n − 1] be calculated like this?

```
u = [dirac(n)];
v = [dirac(n-1)];
w = conv(u,v)
```

I tried that, but it asks me to define (n).
Should the functions be represented as the locations where the functions are equal to one?

```
u = [0];
v = [1];
w = conv(u,v)
```

But that doesn't seem to give a valid answer.  It gave me the answer NaN.